# How to compute an ID counter on the base of a condition in R

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, lag, rlang

let's say one has the following simplified data frame, composed by the variable 'Date' only, that contains a set of dates:

| Date |
| --- |
| 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 |
| 2022-01-02 |
| 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-04 |
| 2022-01-06 |

I need to compute an ID counter variable that assumes values equal to 1 for the first record only and a cumulative value for the remaining ones.
Specifically, if 2 dates are consecutive then the ID counter remains equal to the previous one, otherwise it increases by 1.

By assuming that, R has to return the following table as output:

| Date | ID.Counter |
| --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 |
| 2022-01-02 | 1 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 |
| 2022-01-04 | 2 |
| 2022-01-06 | 3 |

Could someone help me?

I tried to solve this simple problem by running:

```
library(dplyr)
  what_i_have <- c('2022-12-31','2022-12-31','2022-12-31','2022-01-01','2022-01-01','2022-01-02','2022-01-03','2022-01-03')
  what_i_have <- as.data.frame(what_i_have)
  what_i_have <- what_i_have %>% 
    mutate(ID = 1,
           ID = if_else(Date == lag(Date) ,ID = lag(ID),ID+1))
```

but R returns an error in the mutate() statement; specifically, the error is:

> Error in `mutate()`:
> In argument: `ID = if_else(Date == lag(Date), ID = lag(ID), ID + 1)`.
> Caused by error in `if_else()`:
> must be empty.
> Problematic argument:
> ID = lag(ID)
> Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Update*: change in logic. Previous answer far below.

First, we need `Date`-class:

```r
quux$Date <- as.Date(quux$Date)
```

From there,

```r
cumsum(c(1, diff(quux$Date, units = "day") > 1))
# [1] 1 1 1 2 2 3
```

This can be placed directly within an ungrouped `dplyr::mutate` (without the `quux$`).

Data

```r
quux <- structure(list(Date = c("2022-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2022-01-02", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-04", "2022-01-06")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

---

---

*(previous answer)*

I recommend *against* the use of what I call "Excel grouping". In Microsoft Excel, often the most popular/frequent way to do grouped calculations (counting, aggregation, etc) is to look at *this* row's group variable(s) and compare with the *previous* row's group variable(s) to see if anything has changed, and use or reset as appropriate. This method is fragile as it relies wholly on the order of data. (There are some ways around this, but it's a common method.)

Instead in R, I strongly recommend the logic of grouped operations. In base R, this usually involves `ave`, `aggregate`, and `tapply` (others exist); in `dplyr`, this is often simpler by using `group_by(.)` previously in the chain (or, with dplyr_1.1 or newer, `by=` within the `mutate`/`summarize`/other-verb function call). (In `data.table`, the `by=.(...)` argument does the same.)

The benefit of using these grouping methods is that the function being used (whether a named function like `sum` or an anonymous function ala `function(z) sum(z[z>5], na.rm=TRUE)` only sees one group's data at a time ... *regardless of whether the rows are contiguous*.

In *this* case, the group calcs are not complex: we can use `match` in base R, for instance. But I'll extend the dplyr code a little to demonstrate the grouping methodology.

## base R

```r
match(quux$Date, unique(quux$Date))
# [1] 1 1 2 3 3 4
```

## dplyr

(dplyr_1.1 or newer for the `by=`)

```r
library(dplyr)
## dplyr_1.1 or newer
quux %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id(), .by = Date)
#         Date id
# 1 2022-01-01  1
# 2 2022-01-01  1
# 3 2022-01-02  2
# 4 2022-01-04  3
# 5 2022-01-04  3
# 6 2022-01-06  4
## works in dplyr before 1.1 (as well as 1.1 and newer)
quux %>%
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(id = cur_group_id())
```

or we can use `base::match` as above:

```r
quux %>%
  mutate(id = match(Date, unique(Date)))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very clear. Unfortunately, I was wrong compiling the table in the example. I would like to get the variable ID such that it assumes value 1 for the date '2022-01-02' because '2022-01-01' and '2022-01-02' are consecutive dates and so on. Your answer works well but only by differentiating on the date. By the way, I edit the question by fixing the ID in the table what_i_want.